# PGCE usability and validity abroad

Tags: teaching, united-kingdom, education

My two questions are about the English [PGCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postgraduate_Certificate_in_Education) (in my case, I would be interested in Physics).

1) I did a bit of research online (and also know the Italian and French education system from direct experience) and it seems to me that the PGCE is not very useful in order to teach abroad. What about English speaking countries (Australia, Ireland, USA, etc.) and International or British schools?

2) I understand that the PGCE carries the credits of a master degree. Does this make it useful or "spendable" in any other sector? If, for example, after my Teacher Training Year decide to do something different from teaching, would the fact that I acquired a PGCE give me any advantage in comparison with another way of obtaining [QTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualified_Teacher_Status)?

Answer (score 2):

you cannot teach with a PGCE, you need to pass the Agreg or CAPES examinations, at which point you are placed at a school. New teachers have very, very little say in where they teach.

PGCE credits are loosely equivalent to masters credits, but my experience is that few universities will APL them in because it's effectively a professional training course. If you carry on learning at the same institution, they might have a scheme to "convert" the PGCE to an MA or MEd.

Comment: Which country is this for?